# Git unable to update URL base

Tags: salesforcedx, git, github

Trying to start learning DX. I have the project set up and downloaded a simple package from a demo org. But I get an error when I try to commit to Github.

```
/Desktop/GloboHealth/globohealthDX$ git push origin master
```

> fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
>     asked for: https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth/upload/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
>      redirect: https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth
>   `

The result of `git remote -v` is

```
origin  https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth/upload (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth/upload (push)
upstream        https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth.git (fetch)
upstream        https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth.git (push)
```

I can't figure out what is going on here. I followed the link. And it asks for a branch. But I have a master branch set up. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Brooks, what is the output of `git remote -v`?

Comment: Hi David,   I am getting

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really sure how your repo got into this state, but you have two remotes (server repos to which you can push changes from your repo) configured, and one of them (`upstream`) has the wrong URL.

You don't need two remotes here because they're actually both pointing at the same repo, your `bdJohnson72/GloboHealth` repo on GitHub.

I would fix `origin` by doing

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/bdJohnson72/GloboHealth.git
```

and then remove `upstream` by doing

```
git remote rm upstream
```

Then you should be able to push to `origin`.